# Fields of Facebook Real Time Update

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've successfully subscribed to Facebook Real Time updates. When a user updates his profile photo, I receive a message like this:

```
{
  "object":"user",
  "entry":[
    {
      "uid":"499535393",
      "id":"499535393",
      "time":1326210816,
      "changed_fields":[
        "picture"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My quetion is simple: what is the difference between the fields `id` and `uid`?

Comment: Facebook seems to tinker with this functionality again. Move fast and break things :-/ SHould be the same though

Comment: Isn't `id` a property that is returned altogether with every entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.0#receiveupdates the entry should only contain the `id` and not the `uid`.

The `id` of the entry is defined as `the object that has changed`. In your case this is the `id` of the Facebook user. So, I guess you can just ignore the `uid` field.